# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type - Lists

Tags: c, list, pointers

I'm writing a small C program that loads a linked list with file names (only). I'm gonna iterate through this list and parse the content of each file name.

When compiling I receive the following error:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
main.c:26: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "list.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FNODEPTR node = NULL;

    node = create_filename_list();

    add_filename_node(&node, "file1.txt");
    add_filename_node(&node, "file2.txt");

    //Start Logger
    //Watchdog
    //Warehouse 

    //print_filename_list((struct sFilename *)node);

    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",node->chaFilename); //Line 25
        node=node->next; //Line 26
    }

    destroy_filename_list(node);

    exit(0); //0 SUCCESS - 1 FAIL
}
```

list.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#include "list.h"

struct sFilename
{
    char chaFilename[25];
    struct sFilename *next;
};

FNODEPTR create_filename_list()
{
    FNODEPTR node = NULL;

    node = (FNODEPTR) malloc(sizeof (struct sFilename)); // Alocando um nó do tipo sFilename

    return node;
}

void add_filename_node(FNODEPTR *fnFilename, char *chaFilename)
{
    FNODEPTR head = *fnFilename; // head recebe o conteúdo de anAction. head aponta para o mesmo endereço que fnFilename
    FNODEPTR newNode;

    newNode = (FNODEPTR) malloc(sizeof (struct sFilename)); // Alocando um nó do tipo sFilename

    strcpy(newNode->chaFilename, chaFilename); // Copiando o conteúdo de chaFilename para newNode->chaFilename.

    newNode->next = head; // next do novo nó aponta para o início da lista (fnFilename)

    head = newNode; //head é igual a newNode. head recebe o endereço de memória de newNode. head está na mesma posição que newNode
    *fnFilename = head; //o conteúdo de anAction é igual a posição de head
}

void print_filename_list(struct sFilename *fnFilename)
{
   if (fnFilename == NULL)
          printf("Nao ha arquivos ftp a serem carregados\n");
   else {
          printf("Os arquivos que serao carregados no T020 sao:\n");
          while (fnFilename != NULL) {
                 printf("\t- %s\n", fnFilename->chaFilename);//fnFilename->chaFilename);
                 fnFilename = (*fnFilename).next;//fnFilename->next;
          }
   }
}

void destroy_filename_list(FNODEPTR fnFilename)
{
    if(fnFilename != NULL)
    {
        free(fnFilename);
    }
}
```

list.h:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

typedef struct sFilename FNODE;
typedef FNODE *FNODEPTR;

FNODEPTR create_filename_list();
void add_filename_node(FNODEPTR *fnFilename, char *chaFilename);
void remove_filename_node(FNODEPTR *fnFilename);
void print_filename_list(struct sFilename *);
void destroy_filename_list(FNODEPTR fnFilename);

#endif
```

This list will be passed as reference to other functions (modules) that will parse and load the content into a database. Although I can't use node->chaFilename to open the files I need to load into the DB.

I got a new problem, when I call parser function passing *node as reference compiler complains the same as above. Example:

parser.c:

```
//Built-in libs
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Homemade libs
#include "parser.h"
#include "list.h"

int start_parse(FNODEPTR *node)
{
    if(node!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Node is not null\n");
        while(node!=NULL)
        {
            printf("\tNode address %x\n", (unsigned int)node);
            node=node->next;
        };
    }

    return 1;
}
```

parser.h:

```
#include "list.h"

#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H
int start_parse(FNODEPTR *node);
#endif
```

GCC output:

```
gcc -Wall   -c -o parser.o parser.c
parser.c: In function 'start_parse':
parser.c:16: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
parser.c:17: error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for any English mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct sFilename
{
    char chaFilename[25];
    struct sFilename *next;
};
```

This should be defined in list.h file, before the statements:

```
typedef struct sFilename FNODE;
typedef FNODE *FNODEPTR;
```

EDIT::

`int start_parse(FNODEPTR *node)` should rather be `int start_parse(FNODEPTR node)`

Comment: I don't think an `extern` will do it since main.c references the member `node->chaFilename` that is only defined in the list.c file.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson hmm, I must compile the program and see.. I think you're right!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you're right. modifying the answer! Thanks a bunch! :-)

Comment: cool @RibeiroGustavoTI :-) enjoy programming with C. It is my favorite language, besides C#

Comment: Added more info about new scenario. Btw I also love C, but I'm a little bit rusty.

Comment: *before* is not needed, the `struct sFilename` can be defined anywhere. But it needs to be defined before any use of its size `sizeof FNODE` for example, and before use of any members. Here, main.c doesn't have the definition of `struct sFilename`. If you want it to stay "private" to hide its implementation, you will need to create some kind of "list_private.h" file.

Comment: @RibeiroGustavoTI `FNODEPTR` is same as `struct sFilename*`. In the line: `int start_parse(FNODEPTR *node)`, is the same as saying `int start_parse(struct sFilename **node)`. Hence, you'll have to dereference `node` **twice**. That's why you get that error!